# Handling a Dynamic List in OptaPlanner

Tags: optaplanner

I have a list of items with different specifications, including the type and quantity of each item. These items need to be placed into different containers, but the maximum number of items that each container can hold is unknown. As a result, the same item may need to be split into multiple containers. I need to use OptaPlanner to calculate the placement steps.

I have defined the placement steps as follows:

```
@PlanningSolution
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AllocationSolution  {
    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    private List<Placement> placement;
    @ValueRangeProvider
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    private List<Container> containers;
    @ValueRangeProvider
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    private List<Material> materials;
    @PlanningScore
    private HardSoftScore score;
}
```

However, there is an issue here: I cannot know the size of the placement list during OptaPlanner initialization, as I do not know how many steps will be needed to complete the placement. This should be a dynamic list, and I need OptaPlanner to automatically expand it. I have searched for solutions in all available resources, but have not found any. How should I handle this, or should I adjust my model?

i need give a example to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if **reversing the model** allows you to determine the number of planning entities by default. See the [domain modeling guide](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/design-patterns/design-patterns.html#domainModelingGuide).

[image: reverse the model]

2. If that doesn't work, use "the virtual entities" pattern. Basically, allow a Placement to not be used (`nullable=true` etc). Then you need to determine the *maximum* number of placements per dataset in advance, which can be difficult. If this number is too high, it slows does the solving. If this number is too low, it can lead to infeasible results (which is worse).